# New Column with multiple conditions and/or between different columns (strings)

Tags: python, excel, string, if-statement, excel-formula

Im stuck. im tryin to code this excel formula in a code of python but after searchin and tryin diff codes i cant get the solution.

=+IF(AND(K2="inscrito_registro")*OR(L2<>"inscrito_registro")*OR($L2<>"no_necesario")*OR($L2<>""),"con carga","sin carga")

I tried with this code in python but its not correct:

df['Carga']=np.where(df['Registration Status'] == "inscrito_registro" and np.where(df['Estado Cancelacion Cargas'] != "inscrito_registro","con carga","sin carga"))

i just tried this code avodin to try the "or" and its not correct. Any suggestion?

Thnx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  please review the guidelines here in posting a reproducible example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as follows, you don't need a second np.where within the first one

```
df['Carga']=np.where(
    (df['Registration Status'] == "inscrito_registro") & 
    (df['Estado Cancelacion Cargas'] != "inscrito_registro"),
    "con carga",
    "sin carga")
```

use | for the OR condition, and you might need to put the OR conditions in parenthesis

```
 df['Carga']=np.where( 
     (df['Registration Status'] == "inscrito_registro") & 
     ((df['Estado Cancelacion Cargas'] != "inscrito_registro") |
      (df['Estado Cancelacion Cargas'] != "no_necesario")  |
      (df['Estado Cancelacion Cargas'] != "")
     ),
     "con carga", "sin carga")
```

Comment: Thnx that works. the problem comes when i try this:  df['Carga']=np.where(
    (df['Registration Status'] == "inscrito_registro") & 
    (df['Estado Cancelacion Cargas'] != "inscrito_registro") or 
    (df['Estado Cancelacion Cargas'] != "no_necesario") or 
    (df['Estado Cancelacion Cargas'] != "")
    "con carga",
    "sin carga")
df

Comment: see updated solution

Comment: It worse perfect. the only "problem" is the last line of code != ""   dont know how to write the code for NaN so that line works aswell. Anyways Thanks a lot Naveed!

Comment: Glad to hear that. If it’s null instead of empty then use .isnull()   ,

Comment: Thnx man. Ur comment was so helpful. I owe you a bottle of good red wine